# BackBone.JS Displaying a details view of an item in the collection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

I'm just starting out using Backbone.js , I have managed to bring back a list of items from the server, but I'm stuck with the next step which is when an item is clicked a detail view of the model is displayed. In the router I have tried creating a route called "show:id" : "show" , but it does not pick up the route inside my MVC controller inside an ASP.NET MVC3 application , which is decorated with the [HttpGet] verb. A good start would just be to get the show method firing when i hit app.navigate('show/1', true) in the console.

```
 EventDate = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "eventDateID"
});
EventDates = Backbone.Collection.extend(
    {
        model: EventDate,
        url: "WebPortal.MVC/Api/EventsAttending"
        //url: "WebPortal.MVC/events/list"
    });
eventDates = new EventDates();

EventsListView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.template = $("#yourevents-template");
            this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
            window.ViewModel = this.model;
        },

        render: function () {
            var html = this.template.tmpl(this.collection.toJSON());
            $(this.el).html(html);
            return this;
        }
    });




var EventsAdmin = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        eventsListView = new EventsListView({ collection: eventDates, el: ".yourEvents tbody" });
    },
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "/Show/:id": "Show"
    },
    index: function () {
        eventsListView.render();
    },
    Show: function (id) {
        $('#show').html("The id is " + id);
    }



 });


> jQuery(function() {

    eventDates.fetch({
            success: function() {
                //creater the router
                window.app = new EventsAdmin();
                Backbone.history.start();
            },
            error: function() {
                //display a nice error page
            }
        });
});
```

The following is the code in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int userid = 1)
        {
            var FindEvents = new FindEventsByAttendeeRequest { UserID = userid };
            var model = _eventsService.FindEventsByUserID(FindEvents).EventFound;

            return Json(model.Select(c => new
                            {
                                c.EventDate.Event.Description,
                                c.EventDate.Event.Title,
                                c.EventDate.StartDate,
                                userid,
                                eventDateID = c.EventDate.ID,
                                VenueName = c.EventDate.Venue.Name,
                                c.EventDate.VenueID,
                                eventID = c.EventDate.Event.ID,
                                attendeeID = c.ID
                            }).OrderBy(o => o.StartDate).Where(u => u.StartDate.Date >= DateTime.Today), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Show(int ID)
    {
        var FindAttendee = new GetAttendeeRequest {Id = ID};
        var model = _eventsService.GetAttendees(FindAttendee);

        return Json(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember that the routes on the client are totally separate from the routes on your server.  These are routes that respond to hash changes (the # in the address bar).  These don't map to routes on the server.

If you want those routes to fire, you have to create a anchor in your `EventsListView` that that looks something like this:

```
<a href="#/Show/12345">Show Event 12345</a>
```

I hope that's what you meant by firing the route.

Good Luck

Comment: My problem is that I have declared 2 routes in the Router, the first route works fine, (The index method), the second route (Show) is never hit. I'm concerned I haven't created the routes correctly either in the router inside my javascript or on the controller.

Comment: The penny finally dropped, the routes don't map to any server side routes unless we specify them in the url of the model or collection.

Comment: Terrific. Im glad you figured it out